# How to change background color of Ext.Msg.alert Sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to change the background color of alert message box in Sencha Touch but I don’t have any idea about it. By default Sencha Touch shows the black background color of alert box but I want to custom color. So please let me know what is correct way to perform this task?

Here I'm trying to add custom class with alert dialog box but it is not working.

***CSS:***

```
 .test{ Background-color: #d21c1c !important; }
```

***Dialog code:***

```
var dialog = Ext.Msg.alert("Custom alert box!"); 
dialog.getDialog().addClass('testcolor');
```

Comment: You create a CSS class called 'test' but add the class 'testcolor' to you dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Use below css classes to change MessageBox bg color and MessageBox text properties.

// To change messagebox background color

```
.x-msgbox
 {
    background-color: #fff;

 }

// To change messagebox text properties
 .x-msgbox-dark .x-msgbox-text {
    color: #000 !important;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

// To change messagebox title
.x-toolbar-dark .x-title {
    color:#000 !important;
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks
Gendaful